# When to call Dispose() method in WPF application

Tags: c#, wpf, dispose

I have a simple WPF single window application contains Textboxes and Buttons. And I also use NotifyIcon and DateTimePicker of Windows Forms in WPF window. How can I effectively dispose all the controls?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hardly anything in WPF has a `Dispose` method. The vast majority of classes encapsulate purely managed information. You can attach an object into the tree (e.g. via a `Children.Add` method) and you can remove it again - that's how the state management works. It exactly doesn't fit into the `IDisposable` pattern, because once you've removed a control you can add it again, whereas `Dispose` means forever (although you could use `Dispose` to manage it in addition to `Add`/`Remove` methods).

[A discussion about it on the Microsoft forums.](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wpf/thread/afa6cc76-92f4-4144-99c5-e8f5fdc88029/)

There are a few things that ought to be `IDisposable` but aren't, like `DispatcherTimer`, and there's nothing to stop you from implementing `IDisposable` on your own classes. It's up to you when to call `Dispose`; basically when you know you aren't going to be using the object any more.

For a `Window` you just call `Close` to close it, and WPF takes care of everything else.

Answer (score 2):

I would say that the same rule applies in WPF applications as in any other .NET applications: if an object implements `IDisposable`, you should call `Dispose` when you are done using it. If you dynamically load and unload controls, and they do not implement `IDisposable`, just setting any references to `null` (and detaching any event handlers) should be enough for the garbage collector to do its job.

Answer (score 1):

Adhere to [CA1001](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/ms182172.aspx): Let the owning type implement [IDisposable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/aax125c9.aspx).

Renounce the old Windows Forms truth that all controls are [IDisposable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/aax125c9.aspx). Implement and call `Dispose` yourselves.

```
sealed partial class MainWindow : IDisposable {
    readonly IDisposable disposable;
    public MainWindow() {
        disposable = ...
    }

    public void Dispose() {
        disposable.Dispose();
    }

    protected override void OnClosed(EventArgs e) {
        Dispose();
        base.OnClosed(e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If that control is a part of some IContainer (that's the common model in .NET) than your controls just needs implementation of IDisposable. Thus Dispose() will be called automatically when it is appropriate time.